# Color of histogram bin based on the distribution of another variable

Tags: r

Ok this is a tricky one. It might not be possible.

```
test<-data.frame(var.a=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,5), var.b=c(1,2,1,3,2,3,4,3,2,2,1,2,1,2,3,4,1,2))
```

is it possible to color each bin of the hist(test$var.a) histogram based on the distribution of var.b? so that I can tell that in the bin 1 of hist(test$var.a) there there are 50% "ones", 25% "twos" and 24% "threes" of var.b? Some sort of stacked bars inside each bin?

I guess some kind of [spinogram](http://addictedtor.free.fr/graphiques/RGraphGallery.php?graph=117) however the bars should not have the same height (since they represent the frequency of var.a) and inside each bar the frequency of var.b should be color coded.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ggplot2](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/) has just what you're looking for:

```
test<-data.frame(var.a=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,5), var.b=c(1,2,1,3,2,3,4,3,2,2,1,2,1,2,3,4,1,2))

library(ggplot2)
qplot(test$var.a, binwidth = 1, fill = factor(test$var.b))
ggsave("stacked_histogram.pdf")
```

[image: Stacked histogram]

Answer (score 2):

Because I love Base R

```
test<-data.frame(var.a=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,5), 
                 var.b=c(1,2,1,3,2,3,4,3,2,2,1,2,1,2,3,4,1,2))
```

A one-lineR

```
barplot(table(test$var.b, test$var.a))
```

[image]